# Не пойму почему не работает автокик

Tags: php, mysql, vkontakte-api, redbeanphp

Привет всем обитателям данного форума,столкнулся с mysql в коде моего бота.
Выбрал для взаимодействия с базой - RedBeanPhp.
Все команды по типу R::find и т.д работают.

Решил сделать автокик с проверкой на включенность в базе данных.
То бишь. Если в базе за определенной беседой в автокике стоит число 1 - то вышедшего кикает. если 0 - не кикает

```
if($chat_act->type == 'chat_kick_user'){
$exec = R::exec("SELECT `auto_kick` FROM `settings` WHERE `peer_id` = $peer_id");
$exec = $exec["auto_kick"];
if($exec == 1) {
 if($from_id == $member_id) {
$vk->request('messages.removeChatUser', ['chat_id' => $chat_id, 'member_id' => $chat_act->member_id]);
}
}
}
```

В базе данных естественно все хорошо,проверял во вкладке SQL - запрос работает.
Буду рад,если кто-нибудь откликнется о моей проблеме и поможет мне.
Заранее благодарю за помощь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ради таких простых..супер простых трюков Вы решили взять библиотеку ? Зачем ? о.о

Comment: Мне кажется что она для меня удобна) Как говорится на вкус и цвет товарища нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приветствую еще раз всех форумчан.
Решил проблему таким образом.
Решил использовать не R::Exec, а R::Find
Ниже показываю решение.

```
 if($chat_act->type == 'chat_kick_user'){
$select_autokick = R::findOne('settings', 'peer_id = ?', [$peer_id]);
$auto_kick = $select_autokick->auto_kick; 

if($auto_kick == 1) {
 if($from_id == $member_id) {
$vk->request('messages.removeChatUser', ['chat_id' => $chat_id, 'member_id' => $chat_act->member_id]);
}
}
}
```

Суть данного решения - `$select_autokick = R::findOne('settings', 'peer_id = ?', [$peer_id]);` - нахожу в базе данных в таблице настроек бесед айди беседы,затем.

```
 $auto_kick = $select_autokick->auto_kick;
```

- выбираю определенный столбец,а дальше - все как по накатанной.
  Сравниваю значение в $autokick с 1. Если 1 - кикает. 0 - не кикает